# Select the last to a certain date record from the dependent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, subquery, lateral-join

In SQL Server I have 2 tables

table_a

```
card_number reissue_date
1           15.02.2017 00:00:00
2           01.02.2017 00:00:00
3           01.01.2017 00:00:00
```

table_b

```
card_number timestamp               limit
1           01.01.2017 00:00:00     9999
1           01.02.2017 00:00:00     100000
1           01.03.2017 00:00:00     25000
2           01.01.2017 00:00:00     10001
3           01.03.2017 00:00:00     5000
3           01.04.2017 00:00:00     0
```

Expected Result

```
card_number limit
1           100000
2           10001
```

I tried many options in this, I came close to a solution, but I could not display the column "limit", what is the best way to solve this problem?

My wrong decision

```sql
SELECT table_b.card_number, Max(timestamp)
FROM   table_b LEFT JOIN table_a
  ON ( table_b.card_number = table_a.card_number
   AND table_b.timestamp < table_a.reissue_date )
WHERE  table_a.reissue_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY table_b.card_number;
```

It is necessary to make a selection of the latest by date records of the table_b table, but not larger than the date in table_a

The working solution I came to at the moment, I'm not sure if it works correctly, but with my initial data it gave the desired result

```
SELECT card_number, 
       Max(timestamp), 
       Max(limit) AS timestamp 
FROM   table_b 
WHERE  table_b.timestamp < (SELECT reissue_date 
                            FROM   table_a 
                            WHERE  card_number = table_b.card_number) 
GROUP  BY card_number;
```

Comment: please paste text instead of  screenshot

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Can you better describe the desired output? Your explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Excuse my English, I need to get the last set limit for cards, excluding those that have a date greater than the date of the first table

Comment: Why $100k for card #1? Shouldn't it be $25k?

Comment: That is, if the date of creation of the limit is greater than the date of the card, it should not be taken into account.

You need to get the last set limit for each card, given what I wrote above

Comment: The issue is resolved, thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, we can use a row-limiting lateral join to bring the latest record in the second table prior to the timestamp of the first table:

```
select a.card_number, b.*
from table_a a
cross apply (
    select top (1) b.*
    from table_b b 
    where b.card_number = a.card_number and b.timestamp < a.reissue_date 
    order by b.timestamp desc
) b
```

This also eliminates rows that have no match, which is consistent with your data.

Comment: This is what you need, thank you very much

Comment: @TheImpaler: *It is necessary to make a selection of the latest by date records of the table_b table, but not larger than the date in table_a*. But OP's query tells a different story indeed.